# Is there a limit to how much concise information a human can learn adequately?

Tags: brain, information

Like, I am trying to learn more chemistry, but also computer programming from the higher-level programming methodologies, frameworks, languages, APIs, XML, web development, and I'm also hoping to improve especially with computer hardware/electrical engineering, and I am trying to improve my pixel art/graphic design/animation skills all at the same time, that is no set schedule for any, and just learning whatever I get my hands on.

Is it possible to learn this way for a human, or will this eventually become too much, and I'll have to sort them/order what I learn separately?

I have not been seeing very much success, but I do keep learning. The problem? Well, I can't get a good grasp on any subject because I am interchangeably attempting to learn all of the aforementioned subjects sporadically, interchangeably, and without any fine schedule. Is this a wrong way for a human to learn, or is the human brain capable of constantly & linearly learning anything in any order very well?

Comment: You need to distinguish an ambitious learning schedule with lack of focus and concentration. What you describe in your last paragraph sounds more like the latter - try to set aside large blocks of time for each subject and read more in-depth.

Comment: if you just put in some little effort this post can become a good question.